# Sql - Sort by values in a cartesian product

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, cartesian-product

Let's say I have the following data:

```
Product
IdPk  |  Name
-------------
guid1 |  Printer
guid2 |  Oil
guid3 |  Etc.
guid4 |  Etc..

ProductPart
PartIdPk| ItemId | PartName
-------------------------
guid100 | guid1  | Ink
guid101 | guid1  | Paper
guid102 | guid2  | Automobile Fuel
guid103 | guid2  | Cooking

ProductPartType
TypeIdPk| ItemId | PartId  | TypeName
---------------------------------
guid200 | guid1  | guid100 | Cyan            < Types of ink
guid201 | guid1  | guid100 | Magenta
guid202 | guid1  | guid100 | Black
guid203 | guid1  | guid100 | Yellow
guid204 | guid1  | guid101 | Photocopier     < Types of paper
guid205 | guid1  | guid101 | Envelope
guid206 | guid1  | guid101 | Card
guid207 | guid2  | guid102 | Petrol          < Types of automobile fuel
guid208 | guid2  | guid102 | Diesel
guid209 | guid2  | guid103 | Olive           < Types of cooking oil
guid210 | guid2  | guid103 | Sunflower
```

So, each product has one or more parts, and each part has one or more types.

I'm wanting to select a Product, its Parts and its Types. Assume that I could have many thousands of entries, so typically I'd like to filter at the same time as selecting. These three tables will often lead to a cartesian product query, and given that scenario I need to run a query which is equivalent to "give me the top 2 products ordered by (type name where the part is Ink) then (type name where the part is Cooking)"

Does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks in advance

Comment: In fact, your table structure seems rather strange at first look (maybe uncomplete ?) : I would see something like a Product table, a TypeCategory Table (ink, Paper), a Type table refering to TypeCategory (Cyan, Magenta, Black) and a ProductType table (many to many table, with product and specific type). Did I miss something ?

Comment: I was just trying to simplify for brevity, although as far as I can tell the problem domain is similar with the tables you describe - i.e., in a cartesian product where only certain rows represent "columns" if you like, is it possible to construct a query that effectively sorts by those rows? Bearing in mind one can't say "sort by x then by y" because for each row where x has a value, y may be null due to a left outer join

Comment: I would indeed have suggested you the order by x then by y : knowing that you can order by a null value, or make and "Order by (Case When [xx] Is Null Then 'abc' Else 'xyz' End). Once again, please give a case, datas present, desired result. This would makes answer easier

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is just a basic join query on the tables:

```
select ppt.*, pp.PartName, p.Name
from ProductPartType ppt join
     ProductPart pp
     on ppt.PartId = pp.PartId join
     Product p join
     pp.ItemId = p.idPK
where <whatever>
```

Then you can do whatever queries you want.  The "top" query is unclear, because there are no natural things to order on.

I do have a quibble with your data structure, because you have product at both the product part and product part type levels.  For consistency purposes, it is better to have this at only only level, probably product part.

Usually, "cartesian product" join is used to refer to a cross join, not an equi-join.  For performance, you can add indexes onto the tables.  However, you probably won't need them.